# How can I take a field out of an array in Javascript and make another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sending data from my client like this:

```
data = {
    Checked: ??
    Matches: null,
    Text: null,              
}
```

My data is stored like this:

```
var a = {
     "Answers": [
         {
             "answerUId":1,
             "correct":true,
             "checked":true,
             "text":"`public`"
         },
         {
             "answerUId":2,
             "correct":false,
             "checked":true,
             "text":"`static`"
         }
   ]
}
```

How can I get out the values of just the checked field and use it to make another array but with just the one parameter so I can use this to replace the ?? in my code?

What I need is:

```
[ true,
  false ]
```

Comment: means you just want those `Answers` which has `checked:true`?

Comment: What exactly do you want? An `array` with just the value of `checked` from ever set of data?

Comment: I updated the question to show in more detail what I am looking for. I think just a simple array where each row has one value of true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, This should work for you

```
var a = 
{"Answers":
   [
    {"answerUId":1,
     "correct":true,
     "checked":true,
     "text":"`public`"},
    {"answerUId":2,
     "correct":false,
     "checked":true,
     "text":"`static`"},
     {"answerUId":3,
     "correct":false,
     "checked":false,
     "text":"`static`"}
   ]
}

var checkedAnswers = a.Answers.map(function (answer) {
    return answer.checked;
})

console.log(checkedAnswers);
```

`CheckedAnswers` will be an `array` like bellow

```
[ true, true, false ]
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I did not explain well. I just added to the questin to show what I think is needed.

Comment: @Alan no Probs , I just updates my answer, just change `filter` to `map`.